# Bind a context to a scope function to create a function reference in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

If I have the following two functions, I can bind `alpha` to a specific string and pass it on to another higher-order function as shown, but I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to do this?

```
fun foo(alpha: String.(Int, Int) -> Unit) {
    bar { x, y -> "george".alpha(x, y) }
}

fun bar(beta: (Int, Int) -> Unit) {
    // ...
}
```

E.g. I'm wondering if there's some syntax to bind `"george"` to `alpha` so I can do something like this and avoid having to create a new lambda (as above) that simply forwards its arguments:

```
bar("george".bind(alpha))
```

PS apologies if I've gotten my terminology completely wrong. It's `alpha` I'm talking about when I refer to a *scope function* in the question title but perhaps this term is reserved for `apply` etc?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exactly what you're after, but if you're calling `bar` multiple times within `foo`, you could make it more concise using an internal function:

```
fun foo(alpha: String.(Int, Int) -> Unit) {
    fun String.alpha(x: Int, y: Int) = alpha(x, y)
    bar("george"::alpha)
    bar("georgina"::alpha)
}
```